# Unexpected result in long int division of C

Tags: c

I try to make a long int division in C, but I can't get the correct result. I'm curious about the reason why I got the crash and how can I get the correct result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    int64_t a = 0x8000000000000000;
    int64_t b = 0xffffffffffffffff;
    printf("a: %ld; b: %ld\n", a, b);
    int64_t c = a/b;
    printf("a/b: %ld\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ gcc test.c -O2
(base) ➜  ~ ./a.out
a: -9223372036854775808; b: -1
a/b = : -9223372036854775808
(base) ➜  ~ gcc test.c
(base) ➜  ~ ./a.out
a: -9223372036854775808; b: -1
[1]    39193 floating point exception (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

[Result of the division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L3Fk.png)

Comment: 0xffffffffffffffff doens't fit in `int64_t`

Comment: What result do you expect? -- Apart from that and presumed that the compiler accepted your literals as `int64_t`, with "-O2" the compiler most probably optimized the division into a pre-calculated result assigned to `c`. That's why this version doesn't crash. But without optimization the division is done and leads to the reported error. -- Raise the warning level to the maximum and correct any finding.

Comment: 0x8000000000000000 also doesn't fit in `int64_t`.

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, printing `a` and `b`:

```
int64_t a = 0x8000000000000000;
int64_t b = 0xffffffffffffffff;
printf("a:%" PRId64 ", b:%" PRId64 "\n", a, b);
```

Yields the following:

```
a:-9223372036854775808, b:-1
```

However, dividing 64-bit signed integer `INT64_MIN` by `-1` on a 64-bit machine is an [undefined behaviour](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/05/19/c-undefined-behaviors/).

A horrible artifact of two's complement arithmetic is the 'most negative number' problem.  Take this code:

```
int8_t a = -127; //-127 to 127 OK
int8_t b = -1;
printf("a/b: %hhd\n", a/b);
```

This code will work for any value of `a`, *except* for `-128` (`INT8_MIN`).  That's because:

```
1000 0000 (-128)
0111 1111 (bit flip)
1000 0000 (add one, back at -128!!)
```

But actually if you look at the second last step:

```
0111 1111 (bit flip)
```

If you add one to that, we have already overflowed, because the first bit is reserved as a sign bit.

Answer (score 1):

First, try using the right format specifiers. Include `inttypes.h` and use `printf(PRId64 "\n", x);` to print `int64_t x;`. `%ld` is not portable. It might work and might not.

Then note that the answer of the division `int64_t c = a/b;` would be 2^63 if the integers weren't limited in size. But in fact there is no representation for that number using 64-bit 2's complement numbers.  They range from `-2^63` to `2^63 - 1`.  That's what's causing the exception. You've overflowed the arithmetic unit that's doing the division.

Open your textbook to study up on binary integer representation.